# Unable to change default python version in windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, environment

Anaconda 2.3.0 with python 3.4.0 is installed on my Windows PC.

I want to upgrade to python 3.5.

I already created an Anaconda environment using `conda create --name py35 python=3.5`  and activated it using `activate py35`.

After installing python 3.5 and conda 6.0.1, still default version is 3.4.2

even in cmd after activating py35, when I write `python --version` it says:

```
python 3.4.2 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `conda create --name py35 python=3.5` creates a new environment which has no effect, by design, on your default environment. To upgrade the default version do

```
conda install python=3.5
```

(*out of interest, why not go to the latest python release, 3.6? In that case you can just do* `conda update python`)

Comment: I've done this and all requested packages are installed. command prompt shows that there's python 3.5.5 on py35 environment. but still system is using python 3.4.3